# Topological term in the Lieb-Liniger model: two different excitations map to the same state?

Tags: mathematical-physics

The many body Lieb-Liniger Hamiltonian is defined by ($c>0$ throughout )
\begin{equation}
\hat H = -\sum_\ell \partial_{\ell}^2 + 2c\sum_{\ell}\sum_{m<\ell} \delta(x_{m}-x_\ell).
\end{equation}
which leads, due to the Bethe Ansatz, to the well-known constraint on underlying system parameters/Bethe roots:
\begin{equation}
\lambda_j + \frac2L \sum_{\ell=1}^N \arctan\left[\frac{\lambda_j-\lambda_\ell}{c}\right] = 2\pi \xi_j
\end{equation}
with the $\xi_j$ scaled quantum numbers scaled by system size $L$. The equation above described the $N$-vector for the $N$-particle state, and the choice of quantum numbers completely determines the state of the system.

It is further known that choosing the $\xi_j$ symmetrically about $\xi=0$ gives the ground state. This in turn means that even particle, ground state configuration, can be understood to correspond to a lattice of $L\xi_j = 2\pi$ increments, each occurring at $\pi\mod2\pi$ in $L \xi$ space. Similarly, the ground state of odd number of particles exists at symmetric configurations of points obeying $2\pi L\xi_j = 0\mod2\pi$ (rather than $\pi\mod2\pi$).

My question is in regard to excitations on top of this symmetric distribution of quantum numbers, so say, between an $N+1$ and an $N$ particle state for the sake of argument. For example Franchini glosses over the quantum number shifts that must happen so as to obey the above properties. Starting from page 25 on https://arxiv.org/abs/1609.02100, the excitations are discussed and on page 26 a graphical representation of the above story is available.

Suppose we are considering a 7 particle state which we turn into a 6 particle state in all possible combinations. Am I correct to say there are 6 (!!) ways of creating this 6 particle state from the 7 particle state?

The reason I claim this is that in order for the properties to be satisfied, creating a hole at a $\xi_h>0$, the remaining particles must shift $\pi$, i.e. all particles to the "right", but also for another hole created at $\xi_h<0$ the particles must shift $-\pi$, i.e. towards the "left" on the real line. This means that exciting a 7 particle ground state state at the first or the last particle both map to the same 6 particle ground state.

Please see the attached doodle for clarification, the first state is the 7 particle (centered) ground state, then the second and the 8th states are both the 6 particle ground state, and the states with curly brackets are the unique states. "Vertical" lines correspond to points in state space with equal numerical value. What is not clear but *is* intended is that configuration 5 is shifted $+\pi$ w.r.t. the states 2,3,4 and shifted $-\pi$ w.r.t. stated 6,7,8. I hope it's clear.

[image: QuantumNumberDoodle]